# Comparing Quality of Raw Data from Various Hardware Setups

Tags: machine-learning, data-preprocessing

My background is not in ML so please correct any gaps in my question.

I am working on an application trying to discriminate across multiple sounds (eg. bark, glass break, keys jingle etc.). There are a very large number of hardware setups possible (number of microphones, location, type of microphone etc.). I am trying to determine the best hardware setup without running a full machine learning classification each time (very resource intensive and want to remove variability from ML training process). If I have a database of various N setups what algorithm could I use to determine which setups carry the most information (and thus good candidates for full ML training). I have been considering various feature extraction approaches (ie mean SnR, total system signal power etc.) but it's not obvious if that is the best way or how to compare datasets with different channel counts. Can anyone provide advice on best ways to parse and sort raw data to determine the best candidate data sets without going through a full ML design/training?